# Is there a way to setup a Apple Intel compilation environment on a Apple Silicon system?

Tags: virtualization, intel

I need to build a large C/C++ project on Macos, and I need to produce binaries for both Intel and ARM architectures. And the compilation involves tons of homebrew tools.

I have looked at docker images and UTM emulation with no luck.

UTM won't work as explained here: [Run MacOS Intel guest VM in a MacOS M1 host](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434040/run-macos-intel-guest-vm-in-a-macos-m1-host)

This docker image doesn't seem to work on Mac: https://github.com/sickcodes/Docker-OSX/

And setting up a rosetta + intel-only homebrew installation on ARM seems tedious, and probably unrealistic.

Is there any way to emulate a Intel Mac environment on a Macbook M2?

Comment: Why do you need this complexity.  Xcode (and clang/llvm) will generate fat binaries that can include both ARM and Intel code.

Comment: Because we don't use xcode but some other toolchains.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you wouldn't need a specific CPU to produce binaries for that CPU. That is the case in general across operating systems and platforms, and also for the Intel and ARM-based Macs. You just need a cross-compiler.

The ordinary way of doing things for you would be to install C/C++ cross compilers that produce Intel binaries. Depending on your project, that could be gcc or clang. It is a completely normal ARM binary that runs on your M2 MacBook, but it just produces Intel binaries.

You can run a full Intel macOS installation in an emulator, such as for example qemu, but the experience is incredibly slow. Using that to install lots of tools, do configuration and then compile things on a regular basis would be torture.